# Yii2 - how to access html files in root folder?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Google wants to verify my website to delete my gmail app and create new one. I placed a file named `deleteGAPPSnotBefore20151206utc.html` in my root folder.

Google wants to access my website like `site.com/deleteGAPPSnotBefore20151206utc.html`.

How to achieve this in `Yii2`?

Comment: You may using meta-tag

Answer (score 1):

You should place it in web accessible folder. In case of using advanced application, place it in `frontend/web` folder, in case of basic - in `web` folder.

**Update:** Also configure your web server to access this file "as is". For example for `Nginx` add it to `index` section:

```
index index.html index.htm index.php deleteGAPPSnotBefore20151206utc.html;
```

But remember this is temporary addition and don't forget to remove it after you finish with Google.

Comment: @Kartz I updated the answer with information about webserver configuration.

Answer (score 0):

use arogachev answer then browse in www.yourdomain.com/deleteGAPPSnotBefore20151206utc.html